# Identify site visitors who use a 'dev' Browser version

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari, beta

Is it possible to identify visitors to a site who are running a development browser, like Chrome *Canary*, using JavaScript?

Using the User Agent String, it is obviously possible to check out the version of a browser, but as that increments I assume the dev version eventually becomes the standard version and then eventually a legacy version; so targeting a version number would need constantly updating.

e.g. Currently these are the dev and stock versions of Chrome:

**Canary (17/07/15)**
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2457.0 Safari/537.36

**"Stock" (17/07/15)**
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36

I'm using Chrome as an example but I'd also like to target Firefox and Safari beta versions if possible.

The reason is to provide specific content to people who are, well, developer-y.

Comment: I fear there is no way to do this short of a centralized service that keeps track of user agent strings, but I'd love to know as well. I'd like to let support people know if the user's browser is a development version (which we don't officially support).